# System Settings won't start, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: system-settings

Title says it all.

I did `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` and all that stuff, but System Settings still won't open.

I tried opening it from a Terminal, and it returned `Bus error (core dumped)`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: ubuntu20; I just do a `sudo apt-get install unity-control-center`. 
I don't know why it happens from time to time

Answer (score 77):

Try this,

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Tried this not working with ubuntu 18

Comment: How does this explain "Bus error (core dumped)" and why does this fix the problem?

Comment: Worked for me, unity-control-center wasn't properly isntalled. Thanks!

Comment: Worked on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.04.2

Comment: Worked for me too! Mine were suddenly gone in Ubuntu 20

Comment: Didn't work for me. My installation of unity-control-center runs without errors, but it has no gui or commandline output.

Answer (score 54):

And if you are trying to do this with Ubuntu 18.04, try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-control-center
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

This is because Ubuntu decided to switch their user interface from Unity to Gnome.

Comment: How is it a dupe of the answer above??

Comment: Ubuntu decided to switch from unity (the first person said "unity-control-center") to gnome ("gnome-control-center"). The commands are very similar, however Kemin asked how for Ubuntu 18.

Comment: Jake - someone commented that your post was a dupe, I questioned that &  they removed their comment which gives mine no context.  Probably I should just remove mine now that I see comments can be removed..

Comment: yes this worked for 18.04 that  have running on VMWare. but why suddenly it stopped showing?

Comment: This is working totally fine. Thank you very much you saved my day. I was thinking to reinstall Ubuntu in my machine.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue in Ubuntu 20.04 and I run the following command,

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/control-center/
```

*Note: If this works for you, that's great!!! Honestly, I don't know what does it do in behind the scenes.*

Answer (score 1):

With NVIDIA graphics I had to install proprietary nvidia-driver-430.40

I added repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

and ran

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

and reboot

The problem was solved.

If does not work for you. To remove the PPAs run:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

Comment: this was my problem. i just had an "unknown display" which the settings was opening on. i eventually realized and was able to drag it in. then to get rid of that "unknown display" you can either update drivers to the recommended with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall ` or manually switch to a propriety driver in `Additional Drivers`, which the autoinstall did to "(propriety, tested)".

Comment: Installing the latest nvidia-driver-* solved my issue, but only after a reboot. It would be nice to add that to your answer.

Comment: @Eric Fossum thanks. Added reboot.as suggted.