# Ubuntu 16.04 can't open system settings

Tags: dual-boot, system-settings

I'm new to linux and recently installed ubuntu 16.04. The problem is when I try to system settings, nothing happens.. I found a similar question and tried the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864723/system-settings-wont-start-ubuntu-16-04) in it but it didn't work for me.

When I try to open settings through terminal using

```
unity-control-center
```

it gives the following error.

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h: 517: elf_machine_rela_relative: Assertion `ELFW(R_TYPE) (reloc->r_info) == R_X86_64_RELATIVE' failed!
```

I'm dual booting ubuntu with windows 10 and ubuntu is installed in a separate partition.

Also, will I be able to overcome this if I change the desktop environment?

Comment: changed the desktop environment to Gnome from unity.. still no change in the result